# No resource found in xml

Tags: android, xml

I have this error on my xml

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at '^index_0' with value '@array/Tipo_peso').

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
 <string-array name="@string/array_tipo_conversion">
        <item>@array/Tipo_peso</item>  //here show the error
        <item>@array/Tipo_Longitud</item>
        <item>@array/Tipo_Volumen</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="@string/tipos">
        <item>Peso</item>
        <item>Longitud</item>
        <item>Volumen</item>
    </string-array>

   <string-array name="@string/Tipo_peso">
    <item>Kg</item>
    <item>Gramos</item>
    <item>Onza</item>
    <item>Libras</item>
    <item>Toneladas</item>
</string-array>
```

this is the file of strings.xml

```
<string name="Tipo_Volumen">Tipo_Volumen</string>
     <string name="Tipo_Longitud">Tipo_Logitud</string>
     <string name="Tipo_peso">Tipo_peso</string>
      <string name="tipos">tipos</string>
       <string name="array_tipo_conversion">array_tipo_conversion</string>
```

I need translated this in english and spanish

Comment: The other ones are working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an 'identifier' as the value of attribute 'name' in the following line:

```
    <string-array name="@string/Tipo_peso">
```

Consider this:

```
    <string-array name="Tipo_peso">
```

Comment: but I need translated this in english and spanish

Comment: Remember, the attribute 'name' in string-array has nothing to do with the actual array itself. It's just used to refer to the array within your code. To have an localized app, you have to create different folder within your 'res' folder and then create a separate folder for each language you want to include in your app. In all these xml files, the attribute 'name' should remain the same. For more info refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html